# Matrix outputting cell names not content and only one row

Tags: matrix, template-scripting

Matrix 2.5.6
EE 2.6.1

I've got a matrix field that is behaving strangely. It only outputs one row despite having multiple rows added and then only outputs the cell names.

I've copied and pasted the field name and cell names to the template so that there is no chance of typos, but still it doesn't work as expected. I've also created a duplicate matrix field and inserted content into an entry and it behaves the same. There is however another matrix in the same entry with different content that works as expected.

My template code is below

```
          <ul>
          {near_hotels}
            <li><a href="{link}">{hotel}</a></li>
          {near_hotels}
          </ul>
```

I've attached a screenshot of the cell settings
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing the “/” in “{/near_hotels}”.

Comment: I am such an idiot. Time for more coffee.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)